# What exactly is wrong with those SQL-Queries

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, join

i am having a little trouble with this part in my lecture over SQL-Basics.
I think it is not very well explained and i am having a hard time finding any good information on the internet. In my book it says: "It is almost allways an error if two tuple attributes are not linked by an explicit join predicate: "
And then this example:

```
SELECT s.Name, c.Name AS Contact, c.Phone
FROM Suppliers AS s, ContactPersons AS c
WHERE s.Name = 'Shop Rite'
AND c.Phone LIKE '+49 351%'
```

No where is explained what an explicit join predicate is. For me this example just looks fine.
Beforehand there was a similair example:

```
SELECT s.Name, c.Name AS Contact, c.Phone
FROM Suppliers AS s, ContactPersons AS c
WHERE s.SuppID = c.SuppID
```

Which is an ok Join as the books says. I dont really understand what the difference is and what exactly is a JOIN-Predicate?

Also i am sorry for any grammer-mistakes (I am not a native speaker)

Thx in advance!

Comment: meaning old style joins via the where clause versus "join xyandz ON blah blah" perhaps

Comment: Always use explicit `JOIN` syntax; never use comas in the `FROM` clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implicit join syntax:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table1 , Table2
WHERE Table1.id = Table2.id
```

Explicit join syntax:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table1 
JOIN Table2
 ON Table1.id = Table2.id
```

Implicit syntax is fine and it will work, but it's not suggested. It is confusing syntax and may lead to many mistakes , mostly when dealing with more then two tables and when you need to `LEFT JOIN` (the stupid plus sign) . You should make it as a habit to use only the proper syntax of a join.

Here is an example for a query with 6 tables combining `LEFT JOIN`s :

```
SELECT <columns>
FROM YourTable,AnotherTable,ThirdTable,FourthTable,AnotherTable2,AnotherTable3
WHERE YourTable.id = AnotherTable.id(+) AND
      YourTable.sec_id = AnotherTable.Sec_Id(+) AND
      AnotherTable.id (+) = ThirdTable.id(+) AND
      YourTable.id = FourthTable.id AND
      FourthTable.Date = ...
      .......
```

As you can see, I didn't put even half of the conditions, assuming there could be a lot more conditions and it looks like crap.

Comment: Can you tell me why the first implicit join predicate doesn't work and the second one does? I still dont get that part . Thx for the answer so far, it really helped me out a lot allready

Comment: What do you mean by doesn't work? Throws an error? @TilmanZuckmantel

Comment: in my book it says, it leads to nonsense